# How to automatically update an entry daily in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database called `ARTICLES`. Inside Articles, I have a table called `Users`. Inside Users, there is an entry called `Renewal`, which is an `Integer`.

Once Renewal is set, it should decrease by 1 every 24 hours. For example, let's say Renewal is 30. In 24 hours, Renewal should be 29. I do not wish to go inside the entry, and update this field every 24 hours. There will be hundreds of rows with different values for Renewal.

Is there a way to automatically update this entry every 24 hours, so that the entry decreases by 1?

Comment: Cron, if UNIX based.

Comment: @JonStirling I do have the Cron Job form, where I can enter commands, but how do I set an SQL command?

Comment: The same way you would from the command line, or,  write a (PHP if you like) script that does it and just call the script. There should be plenty of examples online.

Comment: Create a php script that decreases the 'renewal' values and then call it with 'curl' from your cron job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach. Instead of counting down in a complicated manner you can simply set an 'expire' date. 30 days from now? Then expire at 19 juli 2016 at 12:00. No need for automatic updates.

Comment: I want the user to see the number of days remaining. If I made Renewal into a datetime, wouldn't that give way to some glitches? For example, I'd gather the current date from the user's clock and then subtract it from the expire date. What if the user changes their computer clock?

Comment: If you know the current date, and the expire date, you know the number of days remaining. Don't ever use the user's clock, use the clock of the server, preferably in UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheduled events in MySQL - [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)

I would check renewal values programatically in you PHP script based on your record timestamp instead of you approach.